# Which JAR contains org.springframework.orm.hibernate.HibernateTransactionManager?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jar

I am trying to use Hibernate+Spring in my application but stuck into following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate.HibernateTransactionManager
```

Tired of googling, could any stackoverflower tell me which JAR contains the above class?

**EDIT**

An important thing that I did not notice was that Spring has different packages for different versions of Hibernate. For Hibernate V3 (which I am using), the appropriate HibernateTransactionManager class would be

`org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager`

instead of

`org.springframework.orm.hibernate.HibernateTransactionManager`.

The JAR containing this (hibernate3) class, as I have discovered is `spring-hibernate3.jar`. Thank you for your replies :)

Comment: @Umar with what are you building your application?

Comment: @c0mrade I am using ANT for building.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jarvana](http://www.jarvana.com/) is a nice resource for this type of questions:

[Search class: dorg.springframework.orm.hibernate.HibernateTransactionManager](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/search?search_type=class&java_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate.HibernateTransactionManager)

Answer (score 2):

its in **spring-orm.jar** . Also make sure that you have this JAR in your classpath

Comment: I do have spring-orm.jar in my classpath, but still getting the same ClassNotFoundException :(

Answer (score 0):

Umar, I see you use ant, have you tried [maven](http://maven.apache.org/)? you just include dependency :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And maven take care downloading and everything for you,

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse there's a very useful plugin called [JAR Class Finder](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/jarclassfinder) that's perfect for these type of problems.